# Issue in sorting using collections

Tags: java, sorting, collections, compare

I am trying to sort the data from a list ,the list has the field id  has :

```
field id :field_38637
field id :field_38469
field id :field_38468
field id :field_38638
field id :field_38637
field id :field_38469
field id :field_38468
field id :field_38468
field id :field_38469
field id :field_38468
field id :field_38637
```

size of list data is 11,for the above list data i am doing a sort has below :

```
    Collections.sort(copedppList, new Comparator() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Field oo1 = (Field ) o1;
            Field oo2 = (Field ) o2;
        if(oo1.getFieldId()!=oo2.getFieldId()){}    
                    return 1;
                      else 
                         return 0;


    });


   for (int i = 0; i < copedppList.size(); i++) {

            Field pp = (Field) copedppList
                    .get(i);
            System.out.println(pp.getFieldID());
        }
```

After sort i am getting the list has

```
field_38468
field_38468
field_38468
field_38468
field_38468
field_38469
field_38469
field_38469
field_38637
field_38637
field_38637
```

Edited:
The similar field id's are be grouped together after sort but it should be grouped as per the incoming list which starts with 38637,38469,38468 ,what is wrong here ?I want to maintain the order of incoming list.

Comment: place all the values of the list into a set.

Comment: `return 1` means greater than. Your code suggests that if `a != b` then `a > b` and `b > a` which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not sorting in your comparator, only checking equality. This would probably work better:

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    Field oo1 = (Field ) o1;
    Field oo2 = (Field ) o2;

    return oo1.getFieldID().compareTo(oo2.getFieldID());
}
```

(Assumes that getFieldID is a non null String)

ps: you don't seem to be using generics, it would enable you to remove all those casts from your code.

**EDIT**

You actually want to group the items, not sort them. The easiest way would be to do that with 2 lists (not tested):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<Field> originalList = new ArrayList<Field>();
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38637"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38469"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38468"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38638"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38637"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38469"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38468"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38468"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38469"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38468"));
    originalList.add(new Field("field_38637"));

    System.out.println(originalList);
    List<Field> groupedList = new ArrayList<Field>(originalList.size());
    while (!originalList.isEmpty()) {
        String id = originalList.get(0).getFieldID();
        for (Iterator<Field> it = originalList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Field f = it.next();
            if (f.getFieldID().equals(id)) {
                it.remove();
                groupedList.add(f);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(groupedList);
}

public static class Field {

    private final String fieldID;

    public Field(String fieldID) {
        this.fieldID = fieldID;
    }

    public String getFieldID() {
        return fieldID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Field{" + "fieldID=" + fieldID + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but i need the data in the same order as incoming list should be grouped 38637,38469,38468  in this order

Comment: @simpy Your list gest sorted - is that not what you wanted? Also by changing your question like you did, you make all answers irrelevant, which makes this whole thread useless for future visitors. I suggest you roll back the changes and add an edit at the bottom of the **original** question, explaining why the proposed answers don't solve your problem.

Comment: @simpy Ok you don't want to sort the list, you want to group the similar items together. So I don't think there is a way to do that with the built-in `Collections.sort()` method.

Comment: @assylias how can i achieve this?

Comment: @assylias getting a exception array Index out of bound

Comment: @simpy I just tried it and it works fine. Added to my edit for a complete example. Your error comes from somewhere else in your code. I suggest you use a debugger to find out what is wrong.

Comment: i have some other data  like private String fieldID;
 /** field value */
 private String fieldValue;
 /** updated by user */
 private String updated_by;
 /** date updated */
 private String dt_updated;
 /** sso of the user updated by */
 private String updatedBySSO;
 private List<String> fieldListValue = new ArrayList<String>();
 private String oldValue;
 private String newValue; which are not getting added to new list

Comment: @assylias i have few more data in pojo class

Answer (score 2):

Read up on the documentation for `compare()`. You are supposed to return either -1, 0 or 1 depending on the relationship between the elements `a` and `b`. You only return either 0 or 1 hence the sorting won't work.

Try reading up on http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Try

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
{
  Field oo1 = (Field ) o1;
  Field oo2 = (Field ) o2;
  return oo1.getFieldID().compareTo(oo2.getFieldID());
}
```